# After Loop ends How do I make it go no next?

Tags: vba

I got the Loop going and next part going from recorded macro. But I want to put them into the same macro and here I get stucked.
Any thought?

```
Sub SkapaPDF()
'
' SkapaPDF Macro
'

Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Uträkning")
Set ws1 = Sheets("TillPDF")


'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("TillPdf").Select
    ws1.Rows("2:2").Select

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
        Sheets("TillPdf").Select
        ws1.Rows("2:2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws1.Rows("2:2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = "0" Then Exit Sub
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PDF").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Sheets("PDF").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="\\naspri01tsivz2.tcad.telia.se\TS-Home136$\lrc691\Documents\Kemikalieskatt\Kemikalieskatt &ActiveCell(Q1).pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I **THINK** you are asking "how do I not `Exit Sub` when the value is "0" but instead exit out of the loop and continue with the rest of my code".  If so, change `Exit Sub` to `Exit Do`.   On second thoughts, maybe that isn't what you are asking - I can't work out what your loop is trying to do - so perhaps you will never get a value of "0" in the copied data.

Comment: Loop is copying info from one sheet to another, First sheet contains lots of vlookup and formulas so I just want the values. But the amount of rows in first sheet can vary there fore I have the Loop stoping when there is 0.  Exit Do looks interesting. How does it work? I can google it.

Comment: I changed to Exit Do but then it just repeated the Loop.

Comment: Solved it. If ActiveCell.Value = "0" Then Exit Do   Now I just have to figure out naming the PDF File at the end. It comes out wrong.